# I get undefined many times from random array

Tags: javascript, html, random

I am doing a random generator in Javascript.

**What doesen't work ?**

I get the `undefined` value very often (~80% of all time) as the first value here in this script. If I make the array bigger, the error occurs less often.

**When will it work ?**

If I make the both arrays with the same amount of entries, I don't get the error.

And if I swap the order in the code of `* two.length);` with `one.length);` it also works.

Can you spot the error? Its driving me crazy and its very strange.

```
var one = ['Abashed',
           'Abhorrent',
           'Party',
           'Zing',
           'Zip',
           'Zippy'];

var two = ['Account', 
           'Wives', 
           'Wills', 
           'Wins',
           'Wounds',
           'Wrecks',
           'Wrists',
           'Writings',
           'Wrongs',
           'Years',
           'Yellows',
           'Young',
           'Youths',
           'Zings',
           'Zips'];

function showrandom() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * one.length);
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * two.length);

  document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = one[rand] + ' ' + two[rand];
}

showrandom();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a reusable function `getRandom(randomArray)` that can be called to get the random numbers.

```js
var one = 
['Abashed',
'Abhorrent',
'Party',
'Zing',
'Zip',
'Zippy'];

var two =
['Account',
'Wives',
'Wills',
'Wins',
'Wounds',
'Wrecks',
'Wrists',
'Writings',
'Wrongs',
'Years',
'Yellows',
'Young',
'Youths',
'Zings',
'Zips'];

function getRandom(randArray){
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * randArray.length);
}
function showrandom() {
  document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = one[getRandom(one)] + ' ' + two[getRandom(two)];
}

showrandom();
```

```html
<div id='random'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use different variables for the random index.

You take the second, longer array as final value for getting a random index. This works fine for the second array, but not for the first array.

```
function showrandom() {
    var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * one.length),
        rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * two.length);

    document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = one[rand1] + ' ' + two[rand2];
}
```

To overcome this problem, you could use a function for getting a random value by handing over the array.

```
function getRandomItem(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

function showrandom() {
    document.getElementById('random').innerHTML =
        getRandomItem(one) + ' ' + getRandomItem(two);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding your first `rand` variable because both of your random values are assigned to the same variable name. This will cause the `undefined` because the first array is shorter as the second. It is an easy fix. Just rename one of the variables.

```
function showrandom() {
  var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * one.length);
  var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * two.length);


  document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = one[rand1] + ' ' + two[rand2];
}
```